# List out wrong email addresses

Tags: php, arrays, regex, codeigniter, object

I'm using CodeIgniter PHP foreach loop to go through my email list, and find out any old emails that did not meet the regex requirement and list them out.

I'm having a bit trouble displaying the result from object.

Here's what I have:

PHP:

```
        $this->db->where('status', 'subscribed');
        $email_preliminary=$this->db->select('email')->get('user'); 

        $email_raw = array();

        foreach ($email_preliminary->result() as $row):

            $email_to_test=$row->email;

            if(filter_var($email_to_test, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)||preg_match('/\d*[1-9]\d*/', $email_to_test))
            {
                $email_raw[] = $email_to_test;
            }

            else{

            }
        endforeach;

        $record_raw=array_unique($email_raw);

        $data['record'] = json_decode (json_encode ($record_raw), FALSE);

        $this->load->view('login&signup/signup_test_view', $data);
    }
```

And in the HTML of Signup_test_view, I have:

```
      <?php foreach ($record->result() as $row): ?>

    <span><?php echo $row->email; ?></span><br>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The error msg says:

Call to a member function result() on a non-object in D:\views\login&signup\signup_test_view.php

But I thought I already converted the array into an object with:

```
  $data['record'] = json_decode (json_encode ($record_raw), FALSE);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi I tried the method as mentioned below and still has no result. Error msg changed to try to get property of non object. Also tried pinrt_r($data['record']) and found out that it's still an array...

Answer (score 0):

Output of `json_decode($str,false)` is an plain object, not having any methods.

Try:

```
<?php foreach ($record as $row): ?>
<span><?php echo $row->email; ?></span><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I assume that `$data['record']` is mapped to `$record` in `signup_test_view.php`.

Comment: Still got the same error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I'm using CodeIgniter. Is that why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

$record is simple array having no method .
 try using $record instead of $record->result() to $record.

Have a good time.